# CSS transition to move dots pagination to left / right on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am trying to achieve some sort of behaviour that transitions (or transforms) a CSS pagination.

I have 5 dots which I want to trigger an animation with when the user clicks the respective button (left or right).

- When the user **clicks left** then dots should animate moving to the left.
- When the user **clicks right** then dots should animate moving to the right.

The dot in the middle should always be centered and there should always be 5 dots visible and the position shouldn't change of the whole pagination.

**So if you click the 'right' button:** The forth dot should swipe left to show it's become the active dot and vice-versa for the clicking the left button.

I am trying to show that the pagination has moved across when the user clicks left or right and this is where I am struggling. Please see code below:

```js
$('.left').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // some animation should happen here to show the pagination has been updated
});

$('.right').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // some animation should happen here to show the pagination has been updated
});
```

```css
.left,
.right {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.pagination {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.dot {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.dot:nth-child(even) {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}

.dot:nth-child(odd) {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
}

.dot.active {
  background: #333;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pagination">
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot active"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="left">
left
</a>

<a href="#" class="right">
right
</a>
```

Comment: Instead of using nth child to colour your dot, use a class like selected, then in your clicks, you can just move that class using `.next` and `.prev` and add and remove class.  But in it's current form, your question is too broad and therefore off topic for SO

Comment: @Pete, i've adjusted the code to your recommendations - can you suggest how you'd implement .next and .prev please?

Comment: `$('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active')`

Comment: @zxynz, I don't quite get it. (And I think no-one here does). Isn't it contradictory what you're asking? Position should not change, dots swiping... but yet the active dot in the middle. I can't picture in my head what you want, therefore I can't code it.

Comment: @DamiánPabloGonzález - if you take a look at this: http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/040-pagination-dynamic.html, it will give some insight on what im trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this snippet, I think it's what you want, according to the example you gave me.

**Explanation:**

Now the pagination has 2 divs: An outter div, think of it as a window, always in the same position, with width enough for seeing 5 dots. (`overflow:none` is very important, for the window only show 5 dots and hide whatever doesn't fit in it). And a inner div with all dots, which we'll be moving left and right.

```js
var currentPage = 2;
processDotPosition();

$('.left' ).click(function() { currentPage -= 1; });
$('.right').click(function() { currentPage += 1; });

$('.left, .right').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  processDotPosition();
});


function processDotPosition(){
  //settings
  var firstNavigableDot = 2;
  var lastNavigableDot = $('.dot').length-3;

  //don't allow going out of range
  if (currentPage<firstNavigableDot) currentPage=lastNavigableDot;
  if (currentPage>lastNavigableDot)  currentPage=firstNavigableDot;
  
  //manage "active" class
  $('.dot').removeClass('active').removeClass('nearActive');
  $('.dot').eq(currentPage).addClass('active');
  $('.dot').eq(currentPage+1).addClass('nearActive');
  $('.dot').eq(currentPage-1).addClass('nearActive');
  
  //slide the inner div (the +35 is for centering the active dot)
  var newPosition = -(currentPage-2)*19;
  $('.paginationInner').finish().animate({left: newPosition});

}
```

```css
.left,
.right {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.paginationOutter {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left:50px;
  width: 100px; /* only show 5 dots */
  overflow: hidden;
  height:18px;
  position: relative;
  
}

.paginationInner{
  position:absolute;
}

.dot {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: height width 1s ease;
}


/* 1st and 5th */
.dot {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
}

/* 2nd and 4th */
.dot.nearActive {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}


/* 3rd */
.dot.active {
  background: #333;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="paginationOutter">
  <div class="paginationInner">
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>    
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="left">
left
</a>

<a href="#" class="right">
right
</a>
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I want except I want there to be 5 dots always visible on a loop. So if you click 'right' twice on your code, you will see 5 dots. I want that to be the initial state and keep looping after that. any chance?

Comment: I edited the code, it looks better now, and it moves smoother when you click several times. But, according to what you said last: That contradicts with your initial specification of "active dot always in center". Think of it: If your initial "currentDot" is 3 (you're asking for it), what if user clicks left?

Comment: I think it's hard to explain without visually understanding. The pagination has no correlation to any content above it. It's just there to show the user they're going back or forward. Your code is perfect logically, but i actually need 5 dots to always be there, and when you click 'next'/'prev' it will just loop through .. do you get what i mean?

Comment: Exactly that! the only bug is that when you reach the end, it doesn't loop through further.

Comment: Why a bug? I intended to be that way. What would you expect to happen when you reach the last navigable dot and press right?

Comment: Ideally, because i'm using this on a swipe event for mobile, when you reach the last dot and swipe right again (or left), then it will go back to the beginning. However like i mentioned this is purely an animation to show the user what direction they are going in, thats why the loop is necessary

Comment: Ok. I think we've reach the point where you can alter the snippet at it is now and make it yours. You can, for example, change `if (currentPage>lastNavigableDot)  currentPage=lastNavigableDot;` to `if (currentPage>lastNavigableDot)  currentPage=firstNavigableDot;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179818/discussion-between-zxynz-and-damian-pablo-gonzalez).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var length = 3;
$('.left').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  length--;
  //console.log(length);
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(".pagination .dot:nth-child("+length+")").addClass('active');    
  if(length<=1)
    length = 6;  
});

$('.right').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  length++;
  //console.log(length);
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(".pagination .dot:nth-child("+length+")").addClass('active');    
  
  
  if(length>=5)
    length = 0;
});
```

```css
.left,
.right {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.pagination {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.dot {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.dot:nth-child(even) {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}

.dot:nth-child(odd) {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
}

.dot.active {
  background: #333;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  transition:0.3s all;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<div class="pagination">
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot active"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="left">
left
</a>

<a href="#" class="right">
right
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when you loop through it doesn't work - and also I mentioned that the active dot must always be in the middle

Comment: correct, however - its still not keeping the active dot in the middle?

Comment: @zxynz I don't understand why the active dot should be on the middle, then what is the use of having so many dots then? Just a question, please don't mind

Comment: it's just an animation to show something is happening when the user swipes left or right. Its sort of like this demo here when you swipe: http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/040-pagination-dynamic.html

Answer (score 0):

Try Following

```js
$('.left').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  
     if($("div.active").prev().length>0)
  {
  $("div.active").removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
  }  

 
});

$('.right').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 

      if($("div.active").next().length>0)
  {
  $("div.active").removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
  } 
});
```

```css
.left,
.right {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.pagination {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.dot {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.dot:nth-child(even) {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}

.dot:nth-child(odd) {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
}

.dot.active {
  background: #333;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pagination">
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot active"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
  <div class="dot"></div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="left">
left
</a>

<a href="#" class="right">
right
</a>
```